# Does regex are really about the preceding element and, if yes, why it is not the case in bash

Tags: regex

According to Wikipedia:

> - The question mark indicates zero or one occurrences of the
>     preceding element. For example, colou?r matches both "color" and
>     "colour".
> - The asterisk indicates zero or more occurrences of the preceding element. For example, ab*c matches "ac", "abc", "abbc", "abbbc", and
>     so on.
> - The plus sign indicates one or more occurrences of the preceding element. For example, ab+c matches "abc", "abbc", "abbbc", and so on,
>     but not "ac".

However, if I create a file named "colour" and use `find -name colou?r` to find it, I have no result:

```
& touch colour
& find -name colou?r
& ...
```

In the same spirit, If I create a file name `ac` and launch `find -name ab*c`, I have no result.

And `find -name ab+c` does not match `abc` in bash.

So does bash have a different support of regex than what Wikipedia describes ?

Comment: The `-name` option uses globbing patterns, not regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-name` option tests the filename against wildcard patterns (aka *glob*), not a regular expression. To use a regular expression, use the `-regex` option:

```
find . -regex '.*colou?r.*'
```

Also, make sure you quote these arguments, otherwise the shell will expand them before passing them to `find`.